# Passive event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add passive event listener in react. This is a part of my jsx code:

```
<div id="test" onTouchStart={{ handler: TouchFunc(), passive: true }}></div>
```

And the function:

```
function TouchFunc(e){
console.log(e);
}
```

The output is:

> undefined

And also I get this error:

> Expected onTouchStart listener to be a function, instead got type object

How do i access the event from that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onTouchStart` should be a function. Change this line to:

```
<div id="test" onTouchStart={this.TouchFunc}></div>
```

To access it in the function:

```
function TouchFunc(e){
  console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you call the function TouchFunc during component render. You should use this code:

```
<div id="test" onTouchStart={{ handler: TouchFunc, passive: true }}></div>
```